# How to solve the problem of the ValueError "expected square matrix" in a constrained minimization problem with the 'trust-constr' method in Python?

Tags: python, constraints, least-squares, minimize, factorization

I would like to determine the coefficients of a least squares problem with the constraints that the coefficients sum up to 1 and that the coefficients are between 0 and 1. The function which is minimized is expressed in the function 'forecast_combination' and the objective is to determine x. However, the 'trust-constr' method factorizes the Jacobian of the constraints (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-trustconstr.html), which provokes the ValueError "expected square matrix". What should I change?

```
from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def combination_jacobian(x, vDataOut, YPred1, YPred2):
    jac= np.zeros_like(x)
    jac[0] = np.sum(-2*np.multiply(YPred1, vDataOut - x[0]*YPred1 - x[1]*YPred2))
    jac[1] = np.sum(-2*np.multiply(YPred1, vDataOut - x[0]*YPred1 - x[1]*YPred2))
    print(jac)
    return jac

def combination_hessian(x, vDataOut, YPred1, YPred2):
    hess = np.zeros((len(x), len(x)))
    hess[0,0] = np.sum(YPred1**2)
    hess[0,1] = np.sum(YPred1*YPred2)
    hess[1,0] = np.sum(YPred1*YPred2)
    hess[1,1] = np.sum(YPred2**2)
    print(hess)
    return hess


def forecast_combination(x, vDataOut, YPred1, YPred2):
    return np.sum((vDataOut - x[0]*YPred1 - x[1]*YPred2)**2)

vDataOut = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((100, 1))+2).values
YPred1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((100, 1))+1).values
YPred2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((100, 1))+7).values

constrained_least_squares = minimize(fun = forecast_combination, x0 = np.array([0.5, 0.5]), method='trust-constr', args = (vDataOut, YPred1, YPred2), jac = combination_jacobian, hess = combination_hessian, constraints=[LinearConstraint([[1, 1]], [1], [1])],bounds=([0, 0], [1,1]), options={'factorization_method': None})
weights = constrained_least_squares.x
```

More details can be found on https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/tutorial/optimize.html#trust-region-constrained-algorithm-method-trust-constr.

Using the factorization method 'SVDFactorization', results in the initial weights (which cannot be the least squares weights) and no error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-cbfef6ae97b2> in <module>
----> 6 constrained_least_squares = minimize(fun = forecast_combination, x0 = np.array([0.5, 0.5]), method='trust-constr', args = (vDataOut, YPred1, YPred2), jac = combination_jacobian, hess = combination_hessian, constraints=[LinearConstraint([[1, 1]], [1], [1])],bounds=([0, 0], [1,1]), options={'factorization_method': None})


~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\thesis\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    620         return _minimize_trustregion_constr(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp,
    621                                             bounds, constraints,
--> 622                                             callback=callback, **options)
    623     elif meth == 'dogleg':
    624         return _minimize_dogleg(fun, x0, args, jac, hess,

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\thesis\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\minimize_trustregion_constr.py in _minimize_trustregion_constr(fun, x0, args, grad, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, xtol, gtol, barrier_tol, sparse_jacobian, callback, maxiter, verbose, finite_diff_rel_step, initial_constr_penalty, initial_tr_radius, initial_barrier_parameter, initial_barrier_tolerance, factorization_method, disp)
    503             stop_criteria, state,
    504             initial_constr_penalty, initial_tr_radius,
--> 505             factorization_method)
    506 
    507     elif method == 'tr_interior_point':

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\thesis\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\equality_constrained_sqp.py in equality_constrained_sqp(fun_and_constr, grad_and_jac, lagr_hess, x0, fun0, grad0, constr0, jac0, stop_criteria, state, initial_penalty, initial_trust_radius, factorization_method, trust_lb, trust_ub, scaling)
     79     S = scaling(x)
     80     # Get projections
---> 81     Z, LS, Y = projections(A, factorization_method)
     82     # Compute least-square lagrange multipliers
     83     v = -LS.dot(c)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\thesis\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\projections.py in projections(A, method, orth_tol, max_refin, tol)
    400             = svd_factorization_projections(A, m, n, orth_tol, max_refin, tol)
    401 
--> 402     Z = LinearOperator((n, n), null_space)
    403     LS = LinearOperator((m, n), least_squares)
    404     Y = LinearOperator((n, m), row_space)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\thesis\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\interface.py in __init__(self, shape, matvec, rmatvec, matmat, dtype, rmatmat)
    516         self.__matmat_impl = matmat
    517 
--> 518         self._init_dtype()
    519 
    520     def _matmat(self, X):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\thesis\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\interface.py in _init_dtype(self)
    173         if self.dtype is None:
    174             v = np.zeros(self.shape[-1])
--> 175             self.dtype = np.asarray(self.matvec(v)).dtype
    176 
    177     def _matmat(self, X):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\thesis\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\interface.py in matvec(self, x)
    227             raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
    228 
--> 229         y = self._matvec(x)
    230 
    231         if isinstance(x, np.matrix):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\thesis\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\interface.py in _matvec(self, x)
    525 
    526     def _matvec(self, x):
--> 527         return self.__matvec_impl(x)
    528 
    529     def _rmatvec(self, x):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\thesis\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_trustregion_constr\projections.py in null_space(x)
    191         # v = P inv(R) Q.T x
    192         aux1 = Q.T.dot(x)
--> 193         aux2 = scipy.linalg.solve_triangular(R, aux1, lower=False)
    194         v = np.zeros(m)
    195         v[P] = aux2

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\thesis\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\basic.py in solve_triangular(a, b, trans, lower, unit_diagonal, overwrite_b, debug, check_finite)
    336     b1 = _asarray_validated(b, check_finite=check_finite)
    337     if len(a1.shape) != 2 or a1.shape[0] != a1.shape[1]:
--> 338         raise ValueError('expected square matrix')
    339     if a1.shape[0] != b1.shape[0]:
    340         raise ValueError('incompatible dimensions')

ValueError: expected square matrix
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. At SO we encourage [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When I run it, I got "NameError: name 'LinearConstraint' is not defined" produced by the second last line.

Comment: You are right! I forgot to include the first line: 'from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint'. I am sorry. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show my code for both methods to solve this problem: solving the original problem and transforming the problem to optimize 1 parameter as suggested by @rpoleski.

As I mentioned in my comment above, the bounds should be formulated differently and the Jacobian and Hessian in the minimize function are not the Jacobian and Hessian of the function that is minimized (‘forecast_combination’), but the Jacobian and Hessian of the constraints.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds

def forecast_combination(x, vDataOut, YPred1, YPred2):
    return np.sum((vDataOut - x[0]*YPred1 - x[1]*YPred2)**2)

vDataOut = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((100, 1))+2).values
YPred1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((100, 1))+1).values
YPred2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((100, 1))+7).values

constrained_least_squares = minimize(fun = forecast_combination, x0 = np.array([0.5, 0.5]), method='trust-constr', args = (vDataOut, YPred1, YPred2), constraints=[LinearConstraint([1, 1], [1], [1])],bounds=Bounds([0, 0], [1,1]))

weights = constrained_least_squares.x
print('Weights of forecast combination regression: ', weights)
```

When using x[1] = 1 - x[0], the same results are obtained.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import Bounds


def forecast_combination(x, vDataOut, YPred1, YPred2):
    return np.sum((vDataOut - x[0]*YPred1 - (1 - x[0])*YPred2)**2)

vDataOut = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((100, 1))+2).values
YPred1 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((100, 1))+1).values
YPred2 = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((100, 1))+7).values

constrained_least_squares = minimize(fun = forecast_combination, x0 = np.array([0.5]), method='trust-constr', args = (vDataOut, YPred1, YPred2), bounds=Bounds([0],[1]))

weights = constrained_least_squares.x
print('Weights of forecast combination regression: ', weights)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the exact problem is, but I'd like to suggest significant changes. You're fitting for `x[0]` and `x[1]`, i.e., 2 parameters. Since you're forcing `x[0]+x[1]=1.`, then the problem is single parameter. You should be looking for `x[0]` only and using `x[1]=x[0]`. This simplifies your task a lot.

#### Edit:

I've changed: `LinearConstraint([[1, 1]], [1], [1])` => `LinearConstraint([[1, 1]], [0.99], [1.01])` and the error is gone.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The error is indeed gone, similar when using the factorization method 'SVDFactorization' (details can be found in the first link in my question). However, again, the weights returned are equal to the initial weights, when I run the code. This is not an expected result, since I set the first vector (YPred1) closer to vDataOut in comparison to the second vector (YPred2). When I change, for example, YPred1 to pd.DataFrame(np.ones((100, 1))+3).values, I would expect x[0] being equal to 1 and x[1] being equal to 0, but it returns the initial weights.

Comment: Why don't you do 1 parameter fit? It's much much simple.

Comment: Yes, that is also possible. However, that does not solve the problem. I have found that the bounds must be formulated by bounds=Bounds([0, 0], [1,1]), so you must import Bounds from scipy.optimize. Moreover, I think the Jacobian and Hessian in the minimize function should not be the Jacobian and Hessian of the function that is minimized (‘forecast_combination’), but the Jacobian and Hessian of the constraints. These will be computed by the ‘trust-constr’ method and therefore the functions for constructing the Jacobian and Hessian could be discarded.